# How do I reference a data file with a macro?

Tags: dataset, stata, stata-macros

I have various Stata data files. These are located in different folders. I also have a single `do` file that uses these files, one at a time.

Is there a way to use a macro to reference a particular dataset in my `do` file?

For example:

```
local datafile = "C:\filepath\mydata.dta"
```

The idea is to use this later in the code as follows:

```
use `datafile', clear
```

Defining the macro as a global variable works. But I don't want to make it global, so it doesn't prevent me from running two separate programs at a time.

The global definition (without the `dta` extension) is:

```
global datafile = "C:\filepath\mydata"
```

This is used as:

```
use "$datafile", clear
```

---

**EDIT:**

My file path has spaces like `C:\A and B report\mydata.dta`. As a result, with the above local definition I get the following error:

> invalid file specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a common error based on a misunderstanding on how local macros
in Stata work.

If your local macro `datafile` is equal to `"C:\A and B report\mydata.dta"`, then the
enclosing double quotes are part of the macro definition process and are not
present in the stored macro.

To see this:

```
local datafile = "C:\A and B report\mydata.dta"

macro list _datafile 
_datafile:      C:\A and B report\mydata.dta
```

Consequently, your `use` command should instead look as follows:

```
use "`datafile'", clear
```

Note that unlike the spaces, which are important, the equal sign (`=`) is in
fact redundant:

```
local datafile C:\A and B report\mydata.dta

display "`datafile'"
C:\A and B report\mydata.dta
```